# How can I get a uitableViewCell by indexPath.row or only row number instead of indexpath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

we can get the UITableViewCell from indexPath easily like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

But i only have the row number not the index path, i am using this code to get the cell .

```
NSArray *visible       = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
NSIndexPath *indexpath = (NSIndexPath*)[visible objectAtIndex:MyRowNumber];
UITableViewCell *tablecell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpath];
```

Tell me whether its a good approarch and if not which one is.

Comment: see this link may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649220/detect-button-click-in-table-view-ios-xcode-for-multiple-row-and-section/31649321#31649321

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `NSIndexPath` with the row number (assuming your table has only one section).

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:yourRowNumber inSection:0];
```