# How to select a button in the tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, tableview

I can select row using the "didSelectRowAt" function in tableview of swift 3. But how do I do other actions when I select a button in a row? I do not know how to select a button in the tableview.

[image]

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649220/detect-button-click-in-table-view-ios-xcode-for-multiple-row-and-section/31649321#31649321

Comment: You want multiple selection or single selection for button.

Comment: I will use multiple selection button.

Comment: you should create a custom uitableviewcell and inside that you should add button and create a delegate inside the tablecell and when button is tapped, call that delegate method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an outlet action: And find the indexpath using this code

```
    @IBAction func memberPicTapped(_ sender:UIButton) {
            var superView = sender.superview
            while !(superView is UITableViewCell) {
                superView = superView?.superview
            }
            let cell = superView as! UITableViewCell
            if let indexpath = YourTableView.indexPath(for: cell){

            }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. It's worked!

Comment: No problem   Travis

Answer (score 0):

Create custom cell 
Write below code inside `cellForRowAt indexPath` of UItableview Method

```
cell.buttonname?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonmethod), for: .touchUpInside)
cell.buttonname.tag = indexPath.section
```

// Button Clicked Method

```
func buttonmethod(_ button: UIButton) {
     print(button.tag)
     // perform some action
}
```

Comment: Is this Swift 3 version code? In my case it doesn't worked.